# When can the Lagrangian be squared without changing the stationary path?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume that the path $y(x)$ makes the functional
$$ S[y] = \int _a ^b L(y, y', x) dx$$
stationary. Under what conditions does 
$$  \int _a ^b L(y, y', x)^2 dx$$
have the same stationary path? And what other functions can be applied to $L$ without changing the stationary path?

The question is inspired by ordinary calculus: The $x$ that makes $f(x)$ extremal also makes $f(x)^2$ extremal, and often it is convenient to minimize the latter.

Oh, and this very technique is used in [this script](http://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2009/Fall/physics130b/Calc_Var.pdf) on page 13 and 14. To give a brief summary, the goal there is to find the geodesic curve that minimizes

$$ \int (g_{i j} \frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\frac{dx^{j}}{dt})^{1/2} dt $$

where $x^i$ are curvilinear coordinates $g_{i j}$ is the metric. And then the author says that it is *easy* to realize that we can also simply use

$$ \int g_{i j} \frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\frac{dx^{j}}{dt} dt$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. OP is asking:

   > When does the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ lead to the same solutions for the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) as the squared Lagrangian $L^2$?

   Well, that's a good question. There is a natural generalization:

   > When does the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ lead to the same solutions for the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) as the Lagrangian $f(L)$, where $f$ is a differentiable function?

   Let's calculate:
   $$\begin{aligned} E_i [f(L)] -f^{\prime}(L)~ E_i[L]~:=~&
   \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial q^i}- \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^i}\right)f(L) \cr
   ~-~& f^{\prime}(L)\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial q^i}- \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^i}\right)L \cr
   ~=~&-f^{\prime\prime}(L)\frac{dL}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}.\end{aligned}\tag{1} $$

   In eq. (1) $E_i[L]$ denotes the $i$th EL eq. for the Lagrangian $L$.

   Sufficient conditions are apparently:

   > - $L$ is a [constant of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion) (COM), and $f^{\prime}(L)\neq 0$ is not zero.
   > - $L(q,t)$ does not depend on velocities $\dot{q}$, and $f^{\prime}(L)\neq 0$ is not zero.
   > - $f$ is a non-constant affine function.
2. But how can we guarantee that $L$ is a COM? Here is a common strategy.

   - If $L$ does not depend explicitly on $t$, then the energy
     $$h~:=~\left(\dot{q}^i\frac{\partial }{\partial\dot{q}^i} -1\right)L \tag{2}$$
     is a COM, cf. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).
   - If moreover $L$ is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) in the velocities $\dot{q}$ of weight $w\neq 1$, then $$L~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\frac{h}{w-1}\tag{3}$$ is also a COM as well!
3. *Main example.* How does the theory from sections 1 & 2 apply to the square root Lagrangian
   $$L~:=~\sqrt{ g_{ij}(q) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j}\tag{4}$$
   for [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)? Well, it fails because of a tiny but important detail: The weight $w=1$ turns out to be exactly one! This is related to the fact that the solutions to the EL eqs. for $L$ in eq. (4) are all parametrized geodesics, but the solutions to the EL eqs. for $L^2$ are only all *affinely* parametrized geodesics.
   See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) Phys.SE post for details.

Comment: What is $E_i $?

Comment: $\uparrow$ See eq. (1).