# Explicit Solution to Euler Lagrange Equation of Shortest Distance between two Points

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, variational-analysis

So if $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ with $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$, I should minimize $L(f)=\int_0^1{|\dot{f(t)}|}dt$. I get a jumble of equations when solving the Euler Lagrange equations with respect to $t$. Would someone help explicitly solving them.  Please avoid using $y'(x)$ since I am trying to generalize this to n space

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the squared Lagrangian cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506272/11127) Math.SE post. The shortest curve between $a$ and $b$ is unsurprisingly a straight line.