# A calculus-based "proof" that the shortest distance between two points is the line segment. Is the argument valid?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I saw a "proof" about the statement

> The shortest distance between two points $A$ and $B$ is the line segment $AB$.

It denoted $y$ as the function of a path between $A$ and $B$. Then it used calculus and found that $y^{\prime\prime}=0$, concluding that $y$ is the line segment $AB$. This proof is verified to have no mistake in calculus. Although I don't have much knowledge about it, I suppose there exist such two suspicion points:

- The path may not have a form $y=f(x)$ because it might be tangled up too much to express in a way where each "$x$" can only map to a single "$y$". Such a pass is seemingly not the shortest, but this is left to be proved.
- A line segment being defined as a path whose function's second derivative is $0$ may be inappropriate. On the contrary, if a segment is defined as the shortest path between two points and a line is defined as infinitively extending a segment might be better. (In this way, the proof is regarding the question

> Prove that a line's function $y=f(x)$ has $y^{\prime\prime}=0$.

In order that the users can judge the proof better, here's a translation. (Chinese originally)

> $$\text ds=\sqrt{(\text dx)^2+(\text dy)^2}=\text dx\cdot\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\text dy}{\text dx}\right)^2}.$$
> From $A$ to $B$:
> $$S_{AB}=\int_A^B\sqrt{1+y'^2}~\text dx.$$
> Plug in the Euler-Lagrange function to get
> \begin{align*}&\frac{\partial \sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}}{\partial x}=0,\\&\frac{\partial \sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}}{\partial y^{\prime}}=\frac{y^{\prime}}{2 \sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}}.\end{align*}
> When $S_{AB}$ reaches minimum,
> $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=0.$$
> Solving gives $y''=0$.

Comment: What is the proof?  It is hard to judge the proof conclusively if we cannot see it.

Comment: @L.F. I could do a translation of it without interpreting perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be preferable.  Please also include the source of the proof if possible.

Comment: Your second concern seems to just be a matter of terminology, not a problem with the proof. For the first concern, it might suffice to consider only a small segment of the path near each point, where it can be treated as the graph of a function. Are we requiring the path to be twice differentiable, or just continuous?

Comment: @Karl If the definition is like I said, the proof would be logically wrong which is a kind of mistake.

Comment: True, and that's for you to verify since we don't know which definitions you're working with.

Comment: You could parameterise the path with $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and would get $x''(t)=y''(t)=0$ from E.L. equations.

Comment: Is part of the proof showing that $y$ is differentiable?  Or are you finding the minimum only among (twice) differentiable curves?

Comment: @GEdgar The proof deals with twice differentiable curves only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path from $A$ to $B$ can be any continuous map $f$ defined on some interval $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=A$ and $f(b)=B$. How do we define the length of a path? For a line segment, we define it as the distance between the end points; for a poly line we define it as the sum of the length of its line segments; for the general case we define it as supremum over all poly line approximations (i.e., poly lines through vertices $f(t_i)$, $0\le i\le n$ where $a=t_0<\ldots<t_n=b$. It is immediate from the triangle inequality that every finite polyline is at least as long as the direct line, hence so is the infinite over such polylines. Unless our path *is* the straight line (and never gives “backwards”), there is an intermediate point $C$ not on the line segment, and again by triangle inequality, the path length is strictly longer than the direct segment.
This shows that the straight line is shortest without assuming $f$ differentiable.

Incidentally, $f(t)=(t^3,t^3)$ is a valid way to describe a path along the main diagonal. It is shortest, but of course, the second derivative by time is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy:

1. Argue that we should minimize the arclength functional $\int_{t_A}^{t_B}\! dt~ \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}$, cf. above comment by Intelligenti pauca.
2. Argue that we might as well minimize the non-square root functional
   $\int_{t_A}^{t_B}\! dt~ (\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$, cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506272/11127) Math.SE post.
3. Derive the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations $\ddot{x}=0=\ddot{y}$.
4. Deduce that this is a line segment.